# jQuery Tabs with Masterpage - space between tabs and tab content

Tags: asp.net, jquery, master-pages, contentcontrol

I'm trying use jQueryUI tabs in a content control.  The code below works on a page that doesn't use a MasterPage.  When I use it in a content control there is a large gray space between the tabs and the content in them.  How do I get rid of this?

I'm using jquery calendars and accordions with no problems in the content pages.

There is a screen shot at this link **[https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpnKV.png][1]**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<div class="demo">
<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="tabs-1">
  <p>This is tab 1 content</p>
 </div>
 <div id="tabs-2">
  <p>Tab 2 </p>
 </div>
 <div id="tabs-3">
  <p>tab 3</p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

![alt text][1]

[1]: [image: Hosted by imgur.com]

Here's how it looks in the same project without a masterpage - it doesn't have all that extra space.

![alt text][1]

[1]: [image: Hosted by imgur.com]

here's the part of the jquery stylesheet that formats the tabs

```
.ui-tabs { padding: .2em; zoom: 1; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav { list-style: none; position: relative; padding: .2em .2em 0; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li { position: relative; float: left; border-bottom-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 .2em -1px 0; padding: 0; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a { float: left; text-decoration: none; padding: .5em 1em; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected { padding-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-width: 0; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a, .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-disabled a, .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-processing a { cursor: text; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a, .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-collapsible .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a { cursor: pointer; } /* first selector in group seems obsolete, but required to overcome bug in Opera applying cursor: text overall if defined elsewhere... */
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 1em 1.4em; display: block; border-width: 0; background: none; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: Do you have any cascading styles written for the master page that could inadvertantly affecting the tabs?

Comment: I'm using the same stylesheets on the stand alone page and it works.  It's only when it's in a content control that is does this

Comment: the only stylesheet is the jquery ui stylesheet

Comment: it's the dark-hive theme

Comment: Content Placeholders don't reneder any extra html, so I have to believe something is wrong with your master page itself...perhaps an unclosed tag, etc. Have you compared the rendered html from the standalone versus the master/content?

Answer (score 1):

Although too late, the answer is:

```
.ui-tabs-nav { height:2em; }
```

Someone else provided it on a similar question here on SO.